# Pushing keys to an array or javascript object?

Tags: javascript

I need to create an array or js object with specific keys, which should be pushed to an empty array or js object. After that, I need to push some specific values according to that keys, something like this:

```
var arr = ["john":["jval1","jval2"], "matt":["mval1","mval2","mval3"]]
```

I know that's not the rigt notation for a js object or an array, but that's the idea.

This is basically what I'm trying to do:

```
var keys = ["john","matt"];             //my keys
var jvals = ["jval1","jval2"];          //my values for key john
var mvals = ["mval1","mval2","mval3"];  //my values for key matt

var arr = [];

for(var i in keys) arr.push(keys[i])  //pushing the names (I need to push this names as keys so next lines should work)

for(var i in jvals) arr["john"].push(jvals[i])  //Trying to push john values, which doesn't work because "john is not a key"
for(var i in mvals) arr["matt"].push(mvals[i])  //Same.
```

This doesn't work at all, so how should I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is the **more shorter version** of the code, using **`forEach`**

```js
var keys = ["john","matt"];             //my keys
var jvals = ["jval1","jval2"];          //my values for key john
var mvals = ["mval1","mval2","mval3"];  //my values for key matt
var object = {}
  keys.forEach(function(key, index) {
    object[key] = index == 0 ? jvals.slice() : mvals.slice()
  });
console.log(object)
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this code doesn't _copy_ the `jvals` and `mvals` arrays as OP's code attempts to do; it uses those arrays directly. If it's desired to copy the arrays, then you could use `... ? jvals.slice() : mvals.slice()` in the assignment inside the `forEach()` callback.

Comment: why to copy the arrays? you mean those values may change in the future?

Comment: We don't know enough about the actual problem that OP is trying to solve to say whether it matters whether we actually copy the arrays or just assign references to them. In real-life code this could make a big difference, because yes, as you mention, if the source array were to change later then it would also change the array stored inside `object` - and vice versa. Since the OP's code does copy the array, it is probably safest to also copy it in your improved code.

Comment: @MichaelGeary, added the change as per your suggestion. thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

Is this you wanted?

Declare arr as object and add keys with empty array.and then push to your keys.

```js
var keys = ["john","matt"];             //my keys
var jvals = ["jval1","jval2"];          //my values for key john
var mvals = ["mval1","mval2","mval3"];  //my values for key matt

var arr = {};

for(var i in keys) arr[keys[i]]=[];

for(var i in jvals) arr["john"].push(jvals[i]);  
for(var i in mvals) arr["matt"].push(mvals[i]);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Yes that's it! Ty so much.

Comment: glad. accept the answer it solved your problem.@RobertoSepúlveda

Comment: for sure I'll, but 6min left

Comment: It's incorrect to use `for...in` on an array. You should use a numeric loop or `forEach()` instead. See Sravan's answer for an example.

Comment: @MichaelGeary why it's incorrect? A friend recommended to me to use that kind of `for´ instead my usual numeric loop.

Comment: If any other code has extended `Array.prototype` with new properties or methods, then a `for...in` loop will include those properties as well as the numerically indexed array elements. Unless you know for sure that this is not the case, then an ordinary `for` loop or `.forEach()` (which executes a `for` loop under the hood) is safer.

Comment: ok, ty for the clarification. Anyways, should I mark Sravan answer as accepted because of that improvement? The thing is this answer applies better to my real code. I'll consider to use numeric loop anyways.

Comment: Also I would change the name of `arr` since it is no longer an array. I'll call it `obj` for the following note: the last two loops are not needed at all. Instead of looping, you can do `obj["john"] = jvals.slice(); obj["matt"] = mvals.slice();`. `.slice()` makes a copy of an array. Or you may not even need to copy the array but can directly assign it, depending on what you are doing.

Comment: I can't really advise on what answer to accept; my one suggestion here is always to wait a while before accepting any answer. As you can see from the two existing answers, each answer brings some different insights to the problem. I recommend waiting a day or so before accepting any answer, so you don't discourage other people from posting answers that may shed even more light on the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
var keys = ["john","matt"];             //my keys
var jvals = ["jval1","jval2"];          //my values for key john
var mvals = ["mval1","mval2","mval3"];  //my values for key matt

var arr = {}; // not []

for(var i in keys) arr.[keys[i]] = [];  //pushing the names (I need to push this names as keys so next lines should work)

for(var i in jvals) arr["john"].push(jvals[i])  //Trying to push john values, which doesn't work because "john is not a key"
for(var i in mvals) arr["matt"].push(mvals[i])  //Same.
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I see what you are trying to do. The first issue with your code is what you do to the `arr` array after pushing the `keys`'s values into it:

```
for(...) {
    arr["john"].push(jvals[i]);
}
```

What you are doing is pretty much saying `arr.john.push(...)`, but `arr` doesn't have a property named `john` that is array. What `arr` does have is an element at the index 0 that has the value of `"john"`. I.e. `arr` pretty much looks like this `arr = ["john", "matt"]`.

Now what you want is to do is change `arr`to be an object and not an array.

This way your code will look like so:

```
var keys = ["john","matt"];
var jvals = ["jval1","jval2"];
var mvals = ["mval1","mval2","mval3"];

var arr = {};

arr["john"] = jvals;
arr["matt"] = mvals;

// Please don't do the above

// Doing the following (using an object literal) is much better, and what most will advice when creating objects in js.

var arr = {
    john: ["jval1","jval2"],
    matt: ["mval1","mval2","mval3"]
};
```